# User.config file for Window service not being created

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2012, windows-services, app-config

I wrote an Windows service that is up and running in Debug mode. However when I compiled it in Release mode and try to run it. The service throws an exception at where it is trying to load Properties.Settings.Default.mysetting. I go to Local Disk\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\myService folder. I only see the user.config built for the debug mode.

From the MSDN documentations, it seems that .net will create this user.config the first time the application is run. I am using InstallUtil.exe to install the service.

Where is this user.config file? And why is it not being created for the release mode service?

Comment: What kind of exception are you seeing? Posting details of exception along with a call stack might help.

Comment: The application eventlog gives the error "Service cannot be started. System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array." Right at the line where I load one of the user settings from Properties.Settings.Default